# Google places autocomplete on modal. Autocomplete hides behinde the modal

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, google-places-autocomplete

Iam using a external component called 'vue-google-autocomplete'. Se github page for the component here:

https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete

I want to implement the autocomplete on a input on a modal. Here is the code for the modal

```
    <b-modal
  id="create-new-modal"
  @ok="handleOk"
  @show="resetModal"
  @hidden="resetModal"
  title="Skapa fraktion titel"
>
  <!-- :title="languageArray.create_fraction_modal_title[languageCode]" -->
  <b-form ref="form" @submit.prevent="onSubmitCreate">
    <!-- :label="languageArray.fraction_input_label[languageCode]" -->
    <b-form-group
      label="fractions address input lbl"
      label-for="fraction-address"
      invalid-feedback="invalid feedback"
    >
      <vue-google-autocomplete
        id="fraction-address"
        class="pac-container"
        classname="form-control"
        placeholder="Start typinggg"
        v-on:placechanged="places_changed"
        :fields="['geometry', 'formatted_address', 'address_components']"
      >
      </vue-google-autocomplete>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-form>
</b-modal>
```

So when i first executed this code the autocomplete was hiding behinde the modal. Thr autocomplete was triggered by the input on the modal but was shown on the first page and was not focused on the modal. So i used this css trick

```
.pac-container {
z-index: 10000;
}
```

The autocomplete was then showing on the modal but it came with another problem. Now the hole input is out of place on the modal. See picture below:

[image]

How can i fix this?

here is the styles from f12 tool

````
       element.style {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
body.m-content--skin-light2 {
    background-color: #f2f3f8;
}
.modal-open {
    overflow: auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
body, .m-smooth-scroll {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: Poppins;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #5867dd;
    --secondary: #ebedf2;
    --success: #34bfa3;
    --info: #36a3f7;
    --warning: #ffb822;
    --danger: #f4516c;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    direction: ltr;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::befo ```
````

Comment: Can you share the input and input container styles from your browsers (from inspect)? It may has a min-width

Comment: @ArthurBorba There you go. I have edited the answer to add the style of the input. The styles of the input-container... not sure what that is. do you mean the modal

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the styles from 'vue-google-autocomplete' by 'input-container'

Comment: @ArthurBorba Ahaa okej well that is it. The 'vue-google-autocomplete' component is the input with the autocomplete

Comment: Okay, and how does it style look like? I see modal, body and html styles at your code

Comment: What do you mean? What do you need?

Comment: Inspect the "vue-google-autocomplete" component with your browser and get It's styles